# How do I get the output of jq to pipe to curl

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, jq

I'm trying to query AWS EC2 ip addresses and use that addresses to curl the version of the box. The query path I could do it but I'm not sure how to get the output of `jq` to `curl`

Here's the command I use

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:App,Values=app01" \
        --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" | jq 'flatten'
```

And this is the results I got

```
[
  "10.xx.xx.xxx",
  "10.xx.xx.xxx",
]
```

What I would like it to be is

`curl http://10.xx.xx.xxx:8081/version`

Comment: Please show the output of the curl command, explain what exactly you want done with duplicate addresses, and whether or not you want the constructed curl command to be executed.

Comment: Is the output valid JSON, or is there really a comma after the last element in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append:

```
| grep -Eo '[0-9.]{7,14}' | xargs -I {} echo curl http://{}:8081/version
```

If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.